# Rails nested form with local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Inside my _cart_item.html.erb I need to display the product name which is associated with the cart_item

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@cart) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :cart_items do |builder| %>
        <%= render "cart_item", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit :submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is _cart_item.html.erb

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
</p>
```

what I am looking for is something like this

```
<h3><%= cart_item.product.name %></h3>
<p>
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
</p>
```

but how can I pass cart_item.product.name to fields_for/render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f.object` contains your cart item since `f` is the cart item builder in the context.

So do:

```
f.object.product.name
```